# Least number of years to make unique pairs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Here is the question:

> we want to hold a math contest for 8 groups, giving each group 6 questions with the following condition : no group has more than one question from each year and each possible pair of the years that the questions are chosen from is not repeated in any other group. what is the minimum number of years we need to choose our questions from considering this restriction?

I believe the answer to this question is more of a counting nature and my proposed solution is as follows:

we apply the pigeonhole principle to the pairs of the years rather than years. so since we have 6 questions for each group, all possible pairs are $\binom62$ and for 8 groups we get $8\times\binom62$. now this should be less or equal to $\binom n2$ and since for each group we are excluding the possible pairs we get this final inequality $ 8\times\binom62 \leq \binom n2 - 8\times\binom62$ . solving this we get $n \geq 23$ which means that $n_\min = 23$.

but the solution provided was a little bit different. the suggested answer was some sort of a constructive proof and then using proof by contradiction to say that this $n=23$ is indeed the minimum. it supposes that there exists $n \leq 22$ and checks for the possibility of occurrences of a year more than once in each group and concludes as said.

when discussing the different approaches I was told that the requisite I checked is necessary but not sufficient, and the fact that both of these solutions yield to the same result, is mere coincidence. I'd appreciate it if the problem in the first solution could be pointed out.

Comment: I think your proof only demonstrates that $n_{min} \geq 23$.  I don't think it shows this minimum can actually be achieved.

Comment: @RobertShore well sir, why is that so? And supposing this is the case, then cannot we claim that this approach is a non constructive proof? I do not have a problem with the first method being wrong but the fact that "why" it's wrong.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your solution. Why are you subtracting $8\times{C(6,2)}$ in the final inequation? What do you mean by: "and since for each group we are excluding the possible pairs"?

Comment: @tps What I'm arguing here for is that when we give the first group 6 questions, we will no longer be able to use those pairs. so we need to subtract those possible pairs which is $\binom62$ from $\binom n2$ for each group that we have given $6$ questions which would amount to the final LHS experssion $\binom n2  - 8\times\binom 62$.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make sense. You are comparing the number of year pairs per group (left side of inequation) to the total number of year pairs (right side). I cannot see why you use the number of pairs per group twice in the formula. Furthermore, for 6 groups this formula will result in $n\ge{20}$ while the correct answer is 21.

Comment: @tps I don't believe 21 is the valid answer. and please note that we have 8 groups of 6 questions not 6 groups of 6 questions! also when we solve this inequality we get $ n \geq 22.415$ or $ n \leq -21.415$ and since must be a positive integer we get 23.

Comment: For 6 groups:
- Group 1 needs 6 new years
- Group 2 needs 5 new years and reuse one year from Group 1
- Group 3 needs 4 new years and reuse one year from Group 1 and one year from Group 2
- Group 4 needs 3 new years and reuse one year from Group 1, one year from Group 2 and one year from Group 3
- Group 5 needs 2 new years and reuse one year from Group 1, one year from Group 2, one year from Group 3 and one year from Group 4.
- Group 6 needs 1 new year and the rest reused from the other groups.
Total number of new years is 21.

Comment: @tps dear sir or madam, it's  **8 GROUPS** ; NOT 6 !!

Comment: Sure I understand that. But I am trying to demonstrate to you that your formula is wrong, and it just worked for 8 groups by complete chance (as it doesn't work for any n number of groups). I somehow feel that you came up with this formula just because it suited the case of n=8. If you cannot accept that fact then it is your problem. I cannot help you anymore. Have a good day!

Comment: @tps I apologize for my ignorance. I just understood the point you made. but why doesn't it work for the $ n = 6$ ? what is being overcounted (or undercounted) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151793/discussion-between-itspaspas-and-tps).